# Angular 4 : HTTPClient alway return an error 0

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Hello i'm in trouble with angular HTTPclient.

I'm using Ionic 3 and Cordova so i cant use JQuery, that's why i use HTTPClient.

I have the following lines in my code :

```
var body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('base64', this.getBase64Image(this.image));
body.set('x_poisson', "" + 0);
body.set('y_poisson', "" + 0);
body.set('x_gabarit', "" + this.points[this.points.length - 2]);
body.set('y_gabarit', "" + this.points[this.points.length - 1]);
body.set('largeur_image', "" + this.image.width);
body.set('hauteur_image', "" + this.image.height);
body.set('pseudo', pseudo);

var url = UrlServeur + "/index.php?module=Homologation&action=traiterPhotoApplication&listeCoin=" + corners;
console.log("[LOG][HOMO] Requesting on url: " + url);

this.http.post(url, body).subscribe(response => {
  console.log("[LOG][HOMO] Homologation response: " + response);
  loading.dismiss();
}, err => {
  console.log(`[ERR][HOMO] Homologation error: (${err.status}) ${err.error}`);
  loading.dismiss();
});
```

The probleme is that HTTPClient considere all response as error and i'm unable to get the body when i'm supposed to recieve a JSON.

Here are the log i have :

```
[17:09:59]  console.log: [LOG][HOMO] Requesting on url: 
            http://X.XXX.XX.XXX/cdp/index.php?module=Homologation&action=traiterPhotoApplication&listeCoin=XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXXX,XXX,XXXX,XXXX
[17:10:28]  console.log: [ERR][HOMO] Homologation error: (0) undefined
```

When i watch on the logs of the serve X.XXX.XX.XXX it look like everything went well.

Thanks for reading, don't hesitate to ask for more informations.

### Edit 1:

When i don't use an `URLSearchParam` the server don't get the post data event when manually setting post type to `application/json` manually

I tried with `ResponseContentType` as text :

```
var options = new RequestOptions();
options.responseType = ResponseContentType.Text;
this.http.post(url, body, options).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(`[LOG][HOMO] Homologation response: ${response}`);
  loading.dismiss();
}, err => {
  console.log(`[ERR][HOMO] Homologation error: (${err.status}) [${err.error}] ${err}`);
  loading.dismiss();
});
```

An i still get the following log : `[ERR][HOMO] Homologation error: (0) [undefined] Response with status: 0 for URL: null`

### Edit 2:

It work when i build the app using `ionic cordova build android --prod` but not if i test using `ionic cordova run android -lc`

Comment: the first you must asked if: the url works if I send the data out off Angular?

Comment: Yes i tried it with an Opera plugin named RestMan and i recieved a correct response.

Answer (score 0):

try send to post a simple obj (not a URLSearchParams)

```
var body:any = {
   'base64':this.getBase64Image(this.image),
   'x_poisson': "" + 0,
   'y_poisson': "" + 0,
   'x_gabarit': "" + this.points[this.points.length - 2],
   'y_gabarit': "" + this.points[this.points.length - 1],
   'largeur_image': "" + this.image.width,
   'hauteur_image': "" + this.image.height,
   'pseudo': pseudo
}
```

You also can try see if the response is "text" and not a json Object

```
this.http.post(url, body,{ responseType: 'text' })
```

Comment: Take a look at *Edit 1* in main post, for formatting purposes.